# jquery date picker looking strange

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, datepicker

My jquery datepicker is looking very strange:

[image]

Here are my dependancies loading:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "getdata/css/custom.css" %} media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "getdata/css/custom2.css" %} media="all">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<td><input class="datepicker" id="endDate1" type="text"/></td>
```

and here is my js:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thx

Comment: Whats inside your custom css? Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Could it be because the input box is inside a table?

Comment: Nope, thats not it. took it out of the table... same deal

Answer (score 1):

As can see its working perfectly, so somewhere your css  has an influence on the `td>input` as you can see the styling is different then mine. I suggest you inspect the input and also the `div` = `#ui-datepicker-div` that contains an `table` that gets pulled from the jQuery because somewhere you are overwriting some style.

```js
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "getdata/css/custom.css" %} media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "getdata/css/custom2.css" %} media="all">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
  
  
  <table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
          <thead class="cf">
            <tr>
                <th>copy</th>
                <th>copy</th>
                <th>copy</th>
                <th>copy</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>data</td>
  <td><input class="datepicker" id="endDate1" type="text"/></td>
  <td>data</td>
  <td>data</td>
  </tr>
          </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem.
I had some css styling that was styling the nth child of the cell. The Jquery code must create some new elements inside the cell and they were therefore inheriting styling as the nth element.

**Bottom line, one cannot use nth element styling in blocks where jquery is going to add its own elements.**

Comment: Glad you solved it, and im sure you could use nth element styling in blocks where jquery is going to add its own elements , you just have to be more spicific with your styling tags eg. `table.mytable tr.tablerow td:nth-child(2) { ... }` this wil target only table that has an class `mytable` , and not the jQuery (datepicker) table cells, hope it make sense.